# Cant delete all connection point of shape in visio

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to delete all connection point of shape using following code
but still some connection point does not get deleted.
I don't understand why this happening

```
For currentRow = 0 To shape.Section(Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts).Count - 1
        shape.DeleteRow Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts, visRowFirst + currentRow
Next currentRow
```

Can anyone put some light on this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time through your loop currentRow is 0. You therefore delete the row with index 0. The second row now becomes the first row and its index changes from 1 to 0. Your loop however increments currentRow to 1 so you skip the new first row. This repeats for each iteration and you skip every second row.

You can simply delete the first row until there are no remaining rows.

```
While Shape.RowExists(Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts, visRowFirst, 0)
  Shape.DeleteRow Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts, visRowFirst
Wend
```

Depending on your application, the simplest solution may be to delete the connection point section:

```
Shape.DeleteSection Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts
```

Comment: deleting section is not good idea because i analyse that it adds new section with new set of rows when deleting whole section